# YouTube Player iFrame flutter component working in local but breaking upon deployment to firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase-hosting

I have created a component using the `youtube_player_iframe` package. It is working in localhost (even in profile and release modes) but it is breaking on deployment to flutter. I am unable to debug it because it is not throwing an exception on my machine.

Here is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:youtube_player_iframe/youtube_player_iframe.dart';

class CustomYtPlayer extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomYtPlayer({super.key});

  @override
  State<CustomYtPlayer> createState() => _CustomYtPlayerState();
}

class _CustomYtPlayerState extends State<CustomYtPlayer> {
  final _controller = YoutubePlayerController.fromVideoId(
    videoId: YoutubePlayerController.convertUrlToId(
            'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GSJPueAJnu8') ??
        "",
    autoPlay: false,
    params: const YoutubePlayerParams(showFullscreenButton: true),
  );
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return YoutubePlayer(
      controller: _controller,
      aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
    );
  }
}
```

I tried all the solutions online but none of them seem to work. Idk what the issue is.